# MongoDB and transactions between two collections

Tags: mongodb, transactions

Assume I have two collections Coll1 and Coll2. Every document in Coll2 can be associated to at most one document in Coll1. I would like to associate a document D2 in Coll2 to a document D1 in Coll1, atomically.

One example of issue is:

1. Client A gets document D1.
2. Client A associates document D2 to document D1.
3. Client B deletes document D1.

Assume requests 2 and 3 are executed concurrently. The server loads document D1 which exists (request 2). The server deletes document D1 (request 2). The server associates document D2 to document D1 (which doesn't exist anymore). I end up with inconsistent data.

I'm looking for a way to avoid this kind of issues with Mongo.

Thanks,
Mickael

Comment: This cannot actually be done atomically in MongoDB. You can replicate 2 phase commits but not atomically.

Comment: @Sammaye So maybe I am using the wrong approach? Documents in Coll2 have their own lifecycle (they don't live in documents in Coll1). Therefore, I'm using a different collection. How is this problem solved in Mongo?

Comment: By sacrificing strict consistentcy by having a delete script which can run on n times on a table and it's relations. Your really using the wrong database if you are looking for strict multi document transactions. You want to use an ACID tedch